# How can i update polkadot js metadata from inside my app?

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, metadata, polkadot-js-extension

i need to check in my dapp when the metadata of my wallet is expired and show a popup telling the user that he needs to update his metadata by clicking an update button on that popup.

i need to do this so that the user can always see all the transaction data when making a transaction, if the metadata is not updated he will see some hex code.

How can i update the metadata from inside my app using polkadot.js library ?
Can i do this using some other library ?
Is there any other library that is better than polkadot.js ?

Answer (score 3):

So generally speaking Polkadot-js exposes two important Classes here that can be expanded upon for metadata: `TypeRegistry`, and `Metadata`. So the simple answer is yes: If you are using the `ApiPromise` (or even just the registry) you can update the metadata within the registry.

```typescript
import { TypeRegistry, Metadata } from '@polkadot/types';

const registry = new TypeRegistry();
const metadata = new Metadata(registry, metaHex);
api.registry.setMetadata(metadata);
```

The following source code for v10.11.2 on `setMetadata` can be found [here](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/0c7fed309059e7e31409b575650e03389ca5d3a2/packages/types/src/create/registry.ts#L575);

You can also use `setMetadata` to set your `signedExtensions`, and `userExtensions`. The `noInitWarn` param will suppress any warning the api might throw when setting the extrinsics and types within the registry.

Edit:

The above answer is useful if you are already utilizing Polkadot-js as the tooling library for your dapp.

Comment: how do i check if the metadata is up to date ?

what is metaHex and do i get it ?

Comment: `metaHex` is just the metadata value is as a scale encoded hexadecimal. You can get it by calling `const metaHex = (await api.rpc.state.getMetadata()).toHex()`. As for updating the metadata, here is a concise answer on checking the version of the metadata: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/1359/1786 One way you can go about this is everytime there is a runtime change, to just update the metadata.

Comment: could you explain me how do i check if there is a runtime change ?

i want to:
1. check if i need to update the metadata in my dapp using polkadot.js
2. show popup asking to if i want to update the metadata
3. click update and in the background update the metadata to the latest version

can you wrtie me down the code i need to run to do this ?